# How to use AWS SDK service's models separately/explicitly without using the full SDK jar

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When we use AWS REST API then we have to write and maintain below code by ourself :

1. Credential provider chain.
2. Setting up the required headers in request which differs with different kind of requests.
3. Code for calculating authorization and signature, MD5, checksum.
4. Create a xml request if it is a PUT operation (Maintain xml template for each kind for request).
5. And we have to write code for parsing the response xml.

I used the sample code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/samples/AWSS3SigV4JavaSamples.zip
For calculating the signature and authorization.

I am having following queries :

1. Do we have any other way to use REST API without writing and maintaining code for above mentioned points ? specially for credential provider chain and parsing the response xml.
2. Is there any way to build and use only service’s models without using full sdk jar by using response xml ?

   Means I want to call s3 rest api and want to convert the response xml to java objects without using complete s3 sdk jar. Can I use only S3 sdk models without using of complete s3 sdk jar ?

Comment: If you want the features of the AWS Java SDK for S3 then you can either use the whole SDK (which is quite large) or just the service-specific SDK for S3 (which is much smaller). Presumably you are already using the latter (it seems to be about 2.5MB for the s3-2 jar file). Is the JAR size a problem for you?

Comment: Jar size is not a problem actually we do not want to use complete S3 SDK we will call rest api and after getting response we want to convert the response xml to java objects. We do not want to import dependencies used by S3 SDK that is why we are trying to find a way to use only request and response models of S3 SDK only.

Comment: Why? You’re going to have to do a lot of work to replace the key SDK functions that you’ll need to emulate.

Comment: Because few of the dependencies of S3 SDK is not passing the security scan (Blackduck scan) that is why we do not want to use full s3 sdk and finding a way to use models only.

Comment: Which dependencies fail and why (if you can share)? Another alternative is to report these to the AWS Java SDK team via a GitHub issue.

Comment: For s3 sdk version 2.10.86 scan is failing for dependency netty-4.1.42.Final jars.
But Is there any way to use models separately ?

Comment: The [AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license, so you can take whatever parts you want and repackage them into your own project (as long as you retain copyrights). Whether you can do this without needing those dependencies is another matter, but only you can decide what you can omit.

Comment: @Parsifal I am not asking for or going to take the part of code I want to know any way AWS itself provides to use its request and response models separately without using sdk jar. Means is there any jar or something which having the models.

Comment: @jarmod Can we change the dependencies version which are not passing in security scan ?